# What columns should I use to set the title of the property in RETS Data Feed?

Tags: wordpress, rets

I have downloaded the data from the rets mls server. Example data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2z4jy5fe8lvxtwa/Book1.xlsx?dl=0) and the metadata field [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dvjim401zf318p/rets-metadata-property-1.csv?dl=0). I am using a wordpress site where each property will be a post. But I am confused which column I should use as a title for a property. I can not use system id as title. Please suggest ideas for what will be the title of the proprerty or I need some other search query to get the property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good choice of having ***ListingID*** in the Title of the Property is always a good choice.

How many characters are you limited for the title?